# Storing XML as String

Tags: java, xml

```
String xml ="<results count="6">
        <result>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>Mark</name>
            <score>6958</score>
        </result>
   </results>"
```

I am trying to store XML data in an string. I have followed the above mentioned syntax.But its not working. Please Help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the quotes in your XML string and remove the line spaces:

```
String xml ="<results count=\"6\">" +
        "<result>" +
        "  <id>1</id>" +
        "  <name>Mark</name>" +
        "  <score>6958</score>" +
        "</result>" +
   "</results>";
```

Comment: Nope, it will not work - Java does not support multiple-line string literals.

Comment: Fixed it by removing line breaks.

Comment: With one ";" at the end it will be fine. ;)

Answer (score 1):

try to escape the special characters inside the string.....

```
String xml ="<results count=\"6\">         <result>             <id>1</id>             <name>Mark</name>             <score>6958</score>         </result>    </results>"
```

or you can use this

```
    String xml ="<results count='6'>         <result>             <id>1</id>             <name>Mark</name>             <score>6958</score>         </result>    </results>"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in Java. String literal can't span multiple lines. Here is how it is done:

```
String xml = "<results count=\"6\">"
    + " <result>"
    + "   <id>1</id>"
    + "   <name>Mark</name>"
    + "   <score>6958</score>"
    + " </result>"
    + "</results>";
```

Also note that any double quote must be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

compiler does not like new lines and double quotes. It should be

```
String xml ="<results count=\"6\">"+
        "<result>" +
            "<id>1</id>" +
            "<name>Mark</name>" +
            "<score>6958</score>" +
        "</result>" +
   "</results>";
```

double quotes need to be escaped with \